# angular 4 animation transition

Tags: angular, typescript

guys i have "span" tag in my template that will show if some statment be true ... i applied some animation on it but it perform it without transition .. it will lose transition why ?

component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-user-new',
    templateUrl: './user-new.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./user-new.component.css'],
    styles: [`span{position: absolute}`],
    animations: [
    trigger('heroState', [
        state('inactive', style({
            backgroundColor: '#eee',
            transform: 'scale(1)'
        })),
        state('active',   style({
            backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
            transform: 'scale(1.1)',
            bottom: '100px'

        })),
        transition('inactive <=> active', animate('2s ease-in'))
    ])
]

})
state:string = "active";
```

my html

```
<h3>user new component</h3>
<form
        [formGroup]="heroUser"
      (ngSubmit)="create(heroUser.value)"
>

    <div></div>
    <span [@heroState]="state" *ngIf="heroUser.controls['name'].touched && !heroUser.controls['name'].valid && heroUser.controls['name'].value != ''">incorrect data inserted</span>
    <span *ngIf="heroUser.controls['name'].touched && heroUser.controls['name'].value == ''">field should not empety</span>

    <span *ngIf="heroUser.controls['name'].valid">nice!</span>
    <input  type="text" name="name" formControlName="name">
    <input type="text" name="username" formControlName="username">
    <input type="text" name="email" formControlName="email">
    <input type="text" name="phone" formControlName="phone">
    <input type="submit" [disabled]="!heroUser.valid">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use states 'void' and '*' when in combination with *ngIf as these align with the DOM element (span) not being rendered or rendered.

```
  trigger('heroState', [
    state('void', style({
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
        transform: 'scale(1)'
    })),
    state('*', style({
        backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
        transform: 'scale(1.1)',
        bottom: '100px'
    })),
    transition(':enter, :leave', animate('2s ease-in'))
])
```